# Break table if height is greater than value

Tags: php, jquery, html-table

I'm working on a script that generates a PHP table containing some values from a MySQL database. The script will be displayed on a TV, so I need to break it if its height is greater than 1280 (I've got this value by completing it with values 'till it fits perfect, then I've used jQuery alert to display its height) and I will use `jquery.cycle.all` plugin to create a slideshow from the tables.

My solution was to use a PHP variable and increment it on each generated  then if I have let's say 13 rows, it echoes `</table><table>`, but the cells must have an exact width so it may add a new line of text (if I have a longer text) on a cell and the table will have more than 1280px height.

Does anybody have any idea about how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solutions:

1. Use the css `overflow: hidden` to prevent content going to the next line and just hide it
2. Use javascript to iterate over each row, calculate the height of the row and remove rows if the total height exceeds 1280px.
3. Use PHP to calculate the length of the text in actual px and how many rows would be used, but that is quite complex.

Comment: Isn't there a way just to "echo" `</table></table>` if the height reaches 1280 px?

Comment: Not that I know of. Best solution I can think of is: A) Write one table containing all rows, B) [using JS] if table height > 1280px goto C, otherwise you're done, C) calculate number of rows where sum of height <= 1280px, D) add <table></table> before original table and move these rows to this new table, E) go back to B checking the original table again

Comment: This idea is very good, but I have some trouble with the steps. 
I've generated the table using PHP, but I don't know how to get make the stept B, C, D and E. I can get the height of each `<td>` by giving them a class and using `$('.row').height();` but I can't handle the other steps. Can you, please, help me with this? If you will, please post it as an answer so I will accept it.